# Flutter Getx multiple lists in body

Tags: flutter, listview, flutter-getx

Got the basic listview working with this code:

```
body: GetX<LokationListeCtrl>(
      builder: (ctrl) => ListView.separated(
        separatorBuilder: _separatorBuilder,
        itemCount: ctrl.lokationListe.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return _lokationTile(ctrl.lokationListe.elementAt(index));
        },
      ),
    ),
```

Ok great, so now I'll just add another list by wrapping the whole thing in a multiple child widget, but even before doing that, I'm already stuck trying to get the first list working:

```
body: Column(
      children: [
        GetX<LokationListeCtrl>(
          builder: (ctrl) => ListView.separated(
            separatorBuilder: _separatorBuilder,
            itemCount: ctrl.lokationListe.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return _lokationTile(ctrl.lokationListe.elementAt(index));
            },
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
```

Here using a Column, but it applies to all widgets with multiple children. The itemBuilder code is simply newer executed.

It seems like a simple and usefull thing to be able to do - the question is HOW to have multiple list in body, the "GetX way" ?

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution. If we introduce a new Scaffold and wrap it in an Expanded, then GetX stops beeing an insulted little boy, and starts smiling again:

```
body: Column(
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: Scaffold(
            body: MyBodyPadding(
              // add space between appbar and first ListTile
              child: GetX<LokationListeCtrl>(
                builder: (ctrl) => ListView.separated(
                  separatorBuilder: _separatorBuilder,
                  itemCount: ctrl.lokationListe.length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    return _lokationTile(
                        ctrl.lokationListe.elementAt(index));
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
```